# Откуда пошла традиция называния автора пособий во множ. числе

Tags: стилистика, история, жаргон, единственное-множественное-число

> Поэтому, на **наш** взгляд, подобные основы следует признать членимыми.

В научной литературе есть традиция обращаться к себе (**единственному** автору) во множественном числе (см. выше). Откуда берет истоки эта традиция? В чем ее причины? Допустимо ли в академическом письме использовать по отношению к себе формы единственного числа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тенденции персонализации и деперсонализации высказывания в научных текстах по-разному проявляются как минимум в трёх аспектах:

1. Различаются в национальных традициях академического письма
2. Различаются по научным областям (в совр. английском для естественных наук характернее "мы", для гуманитарных - "я")
3. Изменяются во времени

Для русской традиции длительное время (до 80-х годов прошлого века) было характерным обезличивание выражаемой позиции, рекомендовалось избегать местоимения "я" в пользу *пассивных* конструкций. Местоимение же "мы" использовалось не только в значении "*мы с вами*" в рассуждениях типа "рассмотрим... здесь мы видим", но и как "*местоимение личной скромности*" (мол за этим стоит работа лаборантов, если не коллектива неназванных соавторов, руководителя и научной школы в целом). В рекомендациях ссылались на личное мнение *Эйнштейна*: "**слову "я" нет места в обсуждении научных тем**" (Einstein A. Essays in science, New York, 1934, c. 113). Позже в английских текстах ситуация стала меняться, для изданий стали рекомендовать выражение личной позиции через местоимение Я. Необходимость международного научного общения через публикации на английском языке потребовала пересмотра позиций и в рекомендациях к написанию русских научных текстов. Но изменения в этом направлении идут с некоторым запаздыванием, что фиксируется соответствующими исследованиями. Примеры статей на эту тему:

Местоимения как средство передачи авторской позиции (Щемелева, 2013)
https://cyberleninka.ru/article/v/mestoimeniya-kak-sredstvo-peredachi-avtorskoy-pozitsii-v-angliyskom-i-russkom-nauchnyh-tekstah

Актив или пассив? "Я" или "мы"? (Кузнецова, Сучкова, 2015)

https://cyberleninka.ru/article/v/aktiv-ili-passiv-ya-ili-my

Answer (score 2):

При написании научных текстов общепринято, что автор называет себя либо в третьем лице, либо в первом лице множественного числа, либо использует безличную форму. В Википедии говорится, что использование "мы" в научных статьях подразумевает "читателя и автора". Но я думаю (в силу распространённости третьего лица и безличной формы), что в первую очередь автор таким образом дистанцируется от собственного субъективного мнения и подчёркивает, что его выводы основаны на принятом в сообществе научном методе.

С некоторых пор использование единственного числа не рекомендуется, хотя в середине прошлого века и ранее было сколько-то распространено. Любопытно было бы узнать, когда наступил переломный момент.

Что-то подобное можно наблюдать также в бизнес-этикете. В некоторых компаниях принято требовать, чтобы ответственное лицо при написании официального письма говорило от имени компании (используя множественное число первого лица), а не от себя лично.

**Дополнение**.

Если речь идёт об учебном пособии, то употребление "мы" более дружелюбно по отношению к читателю и активно вовлекает его в процесс обучения.

В англоязычном интернете намного больше информации об этом вопросе. [Здесь](https://www.editage.com/insights/is-it-acceptable-to-use-first-person-pronouns-in-scientific-writing), например, упоминается, что от первого лица ед.ч. писали работы Эйнштейн, Фейнман, Дарвин, Фрейд и др. известные учёные. Также рекомендуют высказывать от первого лица идеи или подходы, которые не являются общепринятыми.

По некоторым исследованиям единственное число первого лица используется всё реже, а фокус вопроса переносится на выбор между активным и пассивным залогом.